# How to get a docker image of Gentoo running in windows

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi3, gentoo

My main target is to have a PI3 B+ running a Gentoo system.
First I need a Running Gentoo system to create a system for PI3, and I want to have that Gentoo system running in a Docker environment in win10.

There is a repository containing docker files that creates a Gentoo-image. But those requires that you already have a running Gentoo environment. I thought that it already exists runnable Docker images running Gentoo, am I wrong or where can I find them?

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Raspberry pi StackExchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). I'd probably start with [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I' ve allready opened it at your suggestion.